# Compilation in C

Tags: c

What will be output if you will compile and execute the following c code?

```
void main(){
   int huge*p=(int huge*)0XC0563331;
   int huge*q=(int huge*)0xC2551341;
   *p=200;
   printf("%d",*q);
}
```

Comment: why don;t you check?

Comment: Maybe undefined behavior.

Comment: Then post the error message and resolve the problem instead of asking such... yes, frankly, crap. "buddy." How can a program, which is not compilable, have an output!? And its undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: Yes, cad. that is the answer. Thanks!

Comment: `int huge` is not a valid type AFAIK.

Comment: @JohnBode: `huge` pointers are part of the [x86 memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model). This code is probably the ancient junk they still teach in some schools.

Comment: @Michael : Bad attitude will not get you far.  If you cannot compile and run the code, then asking about how you could fix that might be a legitimate SO question. However the `huge` keyword is not standard C - and will either be ignored of fail to compile by a  modern compiler.  Moreover writing to arbitrary addresses is likely to fail on a modern OS.

Comment: Please read this page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant to write the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
   int *p=(int *)0XC0563331;
   int *q=(int *)0xC2551341;
   *p=200;
   printf("%d",*q);
   return 0;
}
```

then the output should be whatever integer value is stored starting at address `0xC2551341`.

I'm not sure what `int huge` is supposed to represent; wider integer types are `long int` and `long long int` (or just `long` and `long long`).  Note that these wider types use the `%ld` and `%lld` conversion specifiers for output, respectively.

Comment: `huge` relates to 16 bit x86 memory access to access addresses outside the current 64Kb segment..  It looks like code from some antique compiler, and will almost certainly seg-fault on a modern compiler and OS.